"Law of total probability analog" for density functions
I have been reading a proof that has some steps that I don't understand. I believe I miss something in terms of densities. Is there any analog for computing $f_X(x)$ by conditioning on a sequence of mutually exclusive events $A_i$ that cover $\Omega$? Maybe something like:
$$f_X(x) = \sum_i f_X(x |A_i)$$
since events $A_i$ are mutually exclusive the densities can be added?
My question came up when I was trying to understand this passage:
*Let $X$ be some continuous random variable, $Z= |X|$ and $S$ be some random variable in $\{-1, 1\}$ then
*
$$f_{Z|S}(z, s) = f_{X|S}(x, s) + f_{X|S}(-z, s), \; \forall z \geq 0$$
I am wrapping my head around this. Clearly, if $z<0$ the density should be zero. If $z$ is non-negative then chances are $X\geq 0$ or $X<0$, these events are mutually exlusive. But i am not sure whats next. Using law of total probability, I would say something like $$f_{Z|S}(z, s) = f_{Z|S, X\geq 0}(z, s)(1-f_X(0)) + f_{Z|S, X<0}(z, s)f_X(0) \\=f_{X|S, X\geq 0}(z, s)(1-f_X(0)) + f_{-X|S, X <0}(z,s)f_X(0)=\\$$
$$= ?$$

The quantity $f_{Z\mid S}(z,s)$ is the conditional density (at $z$) of $Z$ given $S=s$ and is better written in the form $f_{Z\mid S}(z\mid s)$. The point of the formula
$$f_{Z\mid S}(z\mid s)=f_{X\mid S}(z\mid s) + f_{X\mid S}(-z\mid s)$$ is to enable you to compute probabilities such as $P(Z\le b\mid S=s)$ in terms of the conditional density $f_{X\mid S}$. To prove this formula, assume $b>0$ and write
$$\begin{aligned}
P(Z\le b\mid S=s)&=P(|X|\le b\mid S=s) \\
&= P(0\le X\le b\mid S=s)+P(-b\le X\le 0\mid S=s)\\
&=\int_0^b f_{X\mid S}(x\mid s)dx + \int_{-b}^0 f_{X\mid S}(x\mid s)dx\\
&=\int_0^b f_{X\mid S}(z\mid s)dz + \int_0^b f_{X\mid S}(-z\mid s)dz,
\end{aligned}$$ where in the first integral we rename the dummy variable $x$ as $z$, and in the second integral we perform the change of variables $z:=-x$.
